# Using text boxes as a criteria for list boxes in Access 2016

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a form that has 3 list boxes that I am trying to query based off the range given from 2 entry/text boxes.  I'm not sure how to get the script to look at the text boxes.

```vb
Me.lstDailytop.RowSource = " SELECT StockCode, SumOfQTY, Date from qrytpdailystck WHERE [Date] BETWEEN  Me.txtStart.Value And Me.txtEnd.Value"

Me.lstMonthlytop.RowSource = " SELECT StockCode, SumOfQTY, Date from qrytpmonthstck WHERE [Date] BETWEEN Me.txtStart.Value AND Me.txtEnd.Value "

Me.lstYearlytop.RowSource = " SELECT StockCode, SumOfQTY, Date from qrytpyearstck WHERE [Date] BETWEEN Me.txtStart.Value AND Me.txtEnd.Value "
```

When I run this it ask for the value of `Me.txtStart.value` and `Me.txtEnd.value`. I'm assuming there is a way to let VBA know its referring to a object rather than a variable. I am unable to figure it out. Hoping someone knows what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply concatenate the values which requires date conversion from string, Be sure to also `Requery` after assigining statement

```sql
Dim whereClause As String

whereClause = " WHERE [Date] BETWEEN CDate('" & Me.txtStart.Value & "')" _
                 & "             AND CDate('" & Me.txtEnd.Value & "')"

Me.lstDailytop.RowSource = "SELECT StockCode, SumOfQTY, [Date] FROM qrytpdailystck " & whereClause
Me.lstDailytop.Requery

Me.lstMonthlytop.RowSource = "SELECT StockCode, SumOfQTY, [Date] FROM qrytpmonthstck " & whereClause
Me.lstMonthlytop.Requery

Me.lstYearlytop.RowSource = "SELECT StockCode, SumOfQTY, [Date] FROM qrytpyearstck " & whereClause
Me.lstYearlytop.Requery
```

---

Alternatively, you can forgo the building of concatenated SQL string and use one query statement directly on form controls with absolute referencing. Using `NZ()` queries can accommodate if form date values are empty or not.

**SQL** *(save below statements as default assignments in each combobox's respective `RowSource` under Property Sheet, never to be changed)*

```sql
SELECT StockCode, SumOfQTY, [Date] 
FROM qrytpdailystck
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN NZ(Forms!myFormName!txtStart, [Date])
                 AND NZ(Forms!myFormName!txtEnd, [Date])

SELECT StockCode, SumOfQTY, [Date] 
FROM qrytpmonthstck
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN NZ(Forms!myFormName!txtStart, [Date])
                 AND NZ(Forms!myFormName!txtEnd, [Date])

SELECT StockCode, SumOfQTY, [Date] 
FROM qrytpyearstck
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN NZ(Forms!myFormName!txtStart, [Date])
                 AND NZ(Forms!myFormName!txtEnd, [Date])
```

**VBA** *(run below on needed trigger event in macro or module)*

```sql
Me.lstDailytop.Requery    
Me.lstMonthlytop.Requery    
Me.lstYearlytop.Requery
```